# DOJO. DataGrid is displayed in Dialog with interval between rows

Tags: datagrid, dojo, dialog

[image: Datagrid in Dialog (DOJO)]

I'm using DOJO v1.7.2. I've created Datagrid in Dialog widget declaratively.
I've included needed styles and JS to my page.
So I'm getting design issue what is in attached image.

I found using Firebug that some element, which have "dojoxGridMasterHeader" `class`, have custom element `style`.
In my case: `display: block; height: 61px;`
Where is it taken from? And how fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue.
This problem is that I have my custom style. It is for me:

```
    table{
        margin-top:25px;
    }
    table td{
        padding:10px 15px;
    }
```

And **before** DOJO begin to parse I must change this style(change all `margin` and `padding` to `0px` or remove) for DOM elements such as `table` and `table td` ,  may be also for `table th`(I didn't try in this case).

I think DOJO creates element with "dojoxGridMasterHeader" class and set him style which is calculated on base of my custom style.